# Spring Integration Ftp Outbound Gateway special character names in folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using Spring integration's Ftp Outbound Gateway to fetch files from remote ftp server. I am creating copies of file in local directory of my environment. **My problem is** that I am not able to fetch folders with correct name if they contains special characters like é,ú,á,í,ü. My system is configured correctly it does not work only with files retrieved trough this gateway.

Thank you for every answer.

My config looks following:

```
FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(
            delegatingSessionFactory(runtimeSessionFactoryLocator), 
            "mget", 
            "payload"
    );

    gateway.setOptions("-P -R"); 
    gateway.setFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<FTPFile>());
    gateway.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE_IF_MODIFIED);
    gateway.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    gateway.setLocalDirectoryExpression(new SpelExpressionParser()
            .parseExpression("'" + this.ftpStoragePath + "'" + "+#remoteDirectory")
    );
```

I found that Spel can have some issues with those special chars, but did not found the solution to avoid that.

EDIT: I figured out a solution. I missed the DefaultFtpsSessionFactory where I was able to .setControlEncoding("UTF-8");

Comment: You should answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: I am going to do that, Thanks for reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I missed the DefaultFtpsSessionFactory where I was able to .setControlEncoding("UTF-8");